# Python Web Scraping with submission of Select and Radio Button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, drop-down-menu, radio-button

I am interested in getting a python script so as to visit the url"https://www.ura.gov.sg/realEstateIIWeb/resiRental/search.action#district", click on the tab "Search by property type and postal district" and finally choosing the parameters for:
Select the Date of Lease Commencement: "Sep-14" to "Aug-2017"
Select the Property type (radio buttons): "Landed properties"
Select the Postal District (i want to iterate and select all, but there is a limit of 5 at a time, hence ideally there should be a loop of 5s each time)

before submitting "Search".

After pressing search, the python script should click on "Download into CSV".

THe main problem i am facing is that i am not sure how to Click on Tabs or get python to fill up the "Select" and "Radio" buttons.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, i have been stuck because i get to the page, but i am not sure how to "submit" all these input values.

Comment: Use selenium webdriver.

Comment: is that the only way? cant I just code it in python or beautiful soup?